# How to create calculation based on conditions using numpy and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a column where its categorical (house, neighbors, routine). And I have 4 extra columns. The dataset looks like this:

```
print(df)

      type    num_before_cleaning      num_after_cleaning    num_before_removing     num_after_removing
0     house          32                       12                    42                      10
1     house          10                       3                     4                       1
2     neighbors      20                       5                     25                      7
3     routine        40                       21                    62                      35 
4     neighbors      14                       2                     21                      9
5     routine        52                       30                    71                      42
```

and I want for each category in column **type** it will divide `num_before_cleaning / num_after_cleaning`  and `num_before_removing / num_after_removing`

So, the outcome will be for example:

```
print(house_cleaning)
0.64
print(routine_removing)
0.79
```

I know that I should use `np.where` but how can I make it perform calculations after giving it a specific condition? Or is there any other ways I can solve it.

I've tried researching but didn't find any answers.

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Comment: @jezrael I've added the expected output which is for each `type`, it will divide what ends with cleaning so it will calcuate the sum of `num_before_cleaning` and divide it by the sum of `num_after_cleaning`. And same goes to `removing`.

Comment: I only ask if understand what need, but added answer. If not working let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
df1 = df.groupby('type').sum()
df1 = df1.assign(clean = df1.pop('num_before_cleaning').div(df1.pop('num_after_cleaning')),
                 remove = df1.pop('num_before_removing').div(df1.pop('num_after_removing')))
print (df1)
              clean    remove
type                         
house      2.800000  4.181818
neighbors  4.857143  2.875000
routine    1.803922  1.727273
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But it's not want I meant. The output should be a percentage so it will calculate the sum of num_before_cleaning and divide it by the sum of num_after_cleaning. And same goes to removing. So, the output should be a percentage. For example, `Percentage of cleaning for type house: 0.86`. `Percentage for removing for type routine: 0.43`

Comment: @Hamad - sorry, I try understand percentage, how is count `0.86` ? Because in question is `0.64` so not sure about formula

Comment: Sorry if it caused confusion it's just a example of an output not the actual number :)

Comment: @Hamad - Ok, so what is formula? I try count and still failed get `0.86`. :(

Comment: `df['num_after_cleaning].sum() / df['num_before_cleaning'].sum()` and same goes to remove ^^

Comment: But I want to do this formula for each type